# expand a testPoint area in cocos2d when detecting a touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have many sprites in my game,which all have bodies in a b2world. and in order to detect a touch i do the next:

```
currentPosition = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: currentPosition];    
    b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(currentPosition.x/PTM_RATIO, currentPosition.y/PTM_RATIO);

    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) 
    {
        b2Fixture *bf1 = b->GetFixtureList();
        if (bf1->TestPoint(locationWorld) )
        {
            CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
            if (tempSprite.tag==2    ) 
            {
```

now , because my sprite's body is too small,and he is moving, it is very hard to touch it while it moves, so i need to change this code, in order to detect a **wide area** around this sprite also.
how do i expand the testpoint to be +- more 50pixels ??

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a larger fixture to the body and set the sensor flag of the fixture to true. The sensor fixture won't change any of the physics, but you can check if a point falls within its boundaries.

You can create a sensor fixture like this (from SensorTest.h):

```
b2CircleShape shape;
shape.m_radius = 5.0f;
shape.m_p.Set(0.0f, 10.0f);

b2FixtureDef fd;
fd.shape = &shape;
fd.isSensor = true;
body->CreateFixture(&fd);
```

See the Box2D manual, section 6.3 ([PDF](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf)), and SensorTest.h included in the Testbed.

Comment: thanks, but they only write 4 lines there, it seems interesting, can you give me a simple example of that? my way is not good ?

Comment: See my edit, I added a code sample from the included Box2D examples. They're a great resource for learning.